# What is better way to parse user defined methods or class construct written in logs

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have logs which I need to parse and extract values passed to the methods or class construct.

Eg. Log line like

> 10-08-2021 08:10:00.345 | 10-08-2021 08:10:00.345 | Debug | test.importA.yada | sometext - ***[ somefunction(arg1=3,arg2="odd"),somefunction2(arg1=8,arg2="even")]***.

From above line I need to extract string list ( bold italic above). And retrieve argument and function name as well. The list could have same or different functions.

I am able to retrieve string list with regex but to iterate over it as list after changing from string to list, python complains: object not defined or value error. To resolve this I have used exec. BUT want to know if there is more pythonic way to do it.

Looking for expert opinion. As its quite normal where we log function entry - exit with arguments but how we retrieve it. If you dont have access to those function signatures or modules, practically importing all functions that could pop in logs is not possible.

Comment: What's the logger formatter in use? Logging the %(message)s in json format could help or logging json all together

Comment: It is in JSON format. It looks like this: { "message" : "sometext - [func1(arg1=2,arg2='even'), func1(arg1=3,arg2='odd')]"}                              if I extract: "[func1(arg1=2,arg2='even'), func1(arg1=3,arg2='odd')]" which is a list in string and eval it, there is nameerror e.g. eval(string). How do I extract the arguments of the function in list without regex since list May containt other objects.

Comment: I have something promising going on, will post later today.

Comment: you can use `ast` to parse this, since it is just Python source code, but honestly, you should think about logging with something like JSON strings with the data more accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function could have args and kwargs and number of those was unknown, I thought of avoiding slicing everywhere and use some.

```
msg = u' { "message" : "sometext - [func1(arg1=2,arg2=\'even\'), xyz_vcx(arg1=3,arg2=\'odd\')]"}'

lstStr = msg.split(' - ')[1][:-2]
```

Created another function Name `evalstring` which will evaluate `lstSTR` recursively in try exception block, Exception has call to other function `createfunction` which create function based upon pre-defined template. Input to `createfunction` is name derived from traceback message in exception.

In `createfunction`  I simply replace the function name with F string and call the whole string with `exec()`.

The pre-defined template string is like:

```
"""
def {functionname}(*args, **kwargs):
     argdict = {{}}
     argdict["args"]=args
     argdict["kwargs"]=kwargs
     return argdict
"""
```

Let me know if interested in full code.

@LMS Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Given the `message` value in the question, this python will create valid objects by `eval(str)`:

##### Create a list of dictionaries with function name and arguments as k,v

```
import re

msg = u' { "message" : "sometext - [func1(arg1=2,arg2=\'even\'), func1(arg1=3,arg2=\'odd\')]"}'
# get the string representing the list
lstStr = msg.split(' - ')[1][:-2]
#replace 'func1(' with 'dict(...'
arr = re.sub('func1[(]','dict(name="func1",',lstStr)

print(eval(arr)[0])
print(eval(arr)[1])
```

**Result**:

```
{'name': 'func1', 'arg1': 2, 'arg2': 'even'}
{'name': 'func1', 'arg1': 3, 'arg2': 'odd'}
```

This regex patter `func1[(]` will be replaced by `dict(name="func1"` which will create a dictionary and add the function name as item.

##### The regular expression to search for function names could be even generic

```
msg = u' { "message" : "sometext - [func1(arg1=2,arg2=\'even\'), xyz_vcx(arg1=3,arg2=\'odd\')]"}'

lstStr = msg.split(' - ')[1][:-2]
arr = re.sub(r'([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[(]',r'dict(name="\1",',lstStr)

lstOfDict = eval(arr)

print(arr)
print(lstOfDict[0])
print(lstOfDict[1])
print(u'function {} , args: {} {}'.format(lstOfDict[1]['name'], lstOfDict[1]['arg1'], lstOfDict[1]['arg2'] ))
```

**Result**:

```
[dict(name="func1",arg1=2,arg2='even'), dict(name="xyz_vcx",arg1=3,arg2='odd')]
{'name': 'func1', 'arg1': 2, 'arg2': 'even'}
{'name': 'xyz_vcx', 'arg1': 3, 'arg2': 'odd'}
function xyz_vcx , args: 3 odd
```

Comment: Thank you LMC, let me try this.

Comment: @svamol did you get a chance to look at this?

Comment: No, caught into something else. Using Eval is something I am concerned with though.

Comment: The eval in this case will invoke `dict()` but not any function in logs, nothing else should be executed.